# ¿Cómo puedo filtrar documentos de una colección por un campo tipo string llamado fecha_proximo_mantenimiento?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose, filtro

Tengo una colección llamada "inventario_dispositivos" y de esta necesito sacar los documentos que estén próximos al mantenimiento (normalmente son 30 días antes de la fecha próxima a mantenimiento) y por el momento estoy tratando de filtrar los documentos que estén en el campo "fecha_proximo_mantenimiento" a 30 dias de la fecha y no encuentro la forma de hacerlo. "fecha_proximo_mantenimiento" es tipo String. Actualmente uso la librería Mongoose para las consultas a MongoDB en NodeJS

La variable/campo "contrato" es el identificador comun que tienen los documentos y es el que me sirve para agruparlos. Cada X numero de documentos tienen un contrato asociado, algo así como un "Tipo cliente" de una tabla de cliente.

El modelo tiene lo siguiente, mostraré los datos que se usan unicamente ya que el modelo se podría llevar 300 filas:

```
   const mongoose = require('mongoose')
    
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema
    const InventarioDispositivosSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        contrato: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Contrato'
            },
      informacion_equipo: {
            type: Object,
            require: ["sistema_operativo", "ip", "nombre_equipo", "usuario_red"],
            properties: {
      ususario_red: { //Este campo y el modelo en sí funciona como está
                    type: String,
                    required: false,
                    trim: true,
                },
        },
    },fecha_proximo_mantenimiento: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        trim: true,
    }, { collection: 'inventario_dispositivos', timestamps: true })

const InventarioDispositivos = mongoose.model('InventarioDispositivos', InventarioDispositivosSchema)

module.exports = InventarioDispositivos
```

Tengo la siguiente consulta

```
// Con contrato quemado
let contrato = 'contrato1';

 Dispositivos.find(
  {
    //Filtros que se le hacen a la consulta 
    contrato,
    fecha_proximo_mantenimiento: {   
      $exists: true
    }
  },
  {
    //Datos que quiero que se muestren, solo el ID se oculta.
    _id: 0,
    'informacion_equipo.ususario_red': 1,
    fecha_proximo_mantenimiento: 1
  }
).limit(10).then((devices) => {
  console.log(devices)
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
})
```

Una muestra del modelo mostrado y de lo que retorna la anterior consulta:

```
  {
    informacion_equipo: { ususario_red: 'angel.goez' },
    fecha_proximo_mantenimiento: '2021-08-30'
  },
  {
    informacion_equipo: { ususario_red: 'angel.goez' },
    fecha_proximo_mantenimiento: '2021-08-25'
  }
```

Edit:
Tengo la siguiente funcion y me trae documentos con fecha mayor a la fecha de mantenimiento y no entre el rango que especifico que seria entre la fecha y 30 dias antes

```
const desde = moment(new Date() - 30).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

// Con contrato quemado por el momento
let contrato = 'contrato1';


Dispositivos.find({contrato}).where('fecha_proximo_mantenimiento').gte(desde).
lte(moment('fecha_proximo_mantenimiento').format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
.exec(function (err, result) {
  if (err){
      console.log(err)
  }else{
      console.log("Valores vacios o fuera del rango:", result) 
  }
});
```

Comment: Es difícil leer la pregunta ¿podrías editarla por favor? Por favor indica como se llama el campo dentro de __inventario_dispositivos__ junto con su tipo y una muestra de la información que contiene. Intuyo que tiene algo que ver con el campo __fecha_proximo_mantenimiento__ pero en tu consulta de muestra solamente se pregunta si existe. Imagino que la consulta se hace desde node, pero no me queda claro mediante qué librería. Tal vez todo eso ayude a que te contesten más rápido

Comment: Ya lo edito, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que hice fue usar moment.js para darle formato a la fecha y como el formato de fecha es el de ISO (del modelo) lo interpreta correctamente

```
const hasta = moment(new Date()).add(30, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
const desde = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

 Dispositivos.find(
        {
          contrato: data[i],
          fecha_proximo_mantenimiento: {
            $exists: true,
            $gte: desde,
            $lte: hasta
          }
        },
        {
          _id: 0,
          'informacion_equipo.ususario_red': 1,
          fecha_proximo_mantenimiento: 1
        }
      ).then((devices) => {
        if (devices.length === 0) {
          //Se saltan los vacios
        } else {
          //Envio de correos
          console.log(devices)
        }
      }).catch(err => {
        alert(err)
        return devices;
      });
```

Comment: el contrato viene de un array entonces por eso tiene el data[i]